# React version of window.location.replace()?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

As an example, I have this in code for my login button.

```
var rJson = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (rJson.success) {
          console.log("login success");
          window.location.replace(redirectLink);
          }
```

Works just fine, but I feel like there has to be a way to achieve the same thing in something from react-router-dom, similar to how

```
  <Link to="/fooPage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
    <Button>
      Foo
    </Button>                
  </Link>
```

would load the new page in, but not reload the entire window, and with things like my log-in button, I feel like it would be preferable to load the page via the react-router-dom, vs reloading the entire window.
I hope that makes sense.
Everything I found in the react documentation had more to do with using redirects in the HTML portion of a component that gets rendered out, like , vs redirecting the user in code, using window.location.replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React Router V6...

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';  
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/");
```

Goes to home.

Prior to v6 you use the history object...

```
 history.push("/");
```

Either by retrieving it from props or the [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to `window.location.replace` would be

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate('/new-path', {replace: true})
```

Without `replace: true` instead of replacing the new location, it assigns  it. Meaning, when the user clicks the back button, it would go to the path where they were redirected from.

**Side note**

From react-router [useNavigate docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate):

> It's usually better to use redirect in loaders and actions than this hook

So for protected routes, etc. it would be better to use [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect)